# mysql query to find out non existing users

Tags: mysql, join

I am playing with 2 database tables. One is **user** table which contains user details like full name and active(whether the user is active or not) columns. The other one is **tasks** table which contains the task details of each user. So tasks table has columns called UserID and StartTime. The following query will display all user details who entered the tasks yesterday.

```
$today = mktime(0,0,0);
$yesterday = $today - 86400;
$res = $db->fetchAll("SELECT DISTINCT tasks.UserID,user.full_name FROM `tasks` JOIN `user` ON tasks.UserID=user.id WHERE user.active=1 AND tasks.StartTime > ".$db->quote($yesterday,'integer')." AND tasks.StartTime < ".$db->quote($today,'integer'));
```

I need to find out the user details who doesn't enter the tasks yesterday. How can I modify the above query?

Thanks!

Comment: it would help if you posted the schema/data for both tables

Comment: Instead of the smaller and bigger starttime, why dont you use [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tasks.UserID, user.full_name FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `tasks` 
ON user.id=tasks.UserID WHERE user.active=1 AND tasks.StartTime = NULL;
```

MySQL should return NULL when it can't find a user in the tasks table.

Comment: A `JOIN` in that query will not return rows for users without task entries.  You'd need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to get users without tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this query will only display if there is one user doesn't have any task details. I need to display if the user doesn't have any task details from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting just the yesterday records from tasks table before joining?

```
"SELECT DISTINCT tasks.UserID, user.full_name FROM `user` LEFT JOIN (
    select * from `tasks` where tasks.StartTime > ".$db->quote($yesterday,'integer')."
    ) `tasks_from_yesterday` 
    ON user.id=tasks_from_yesterday.UserID WHERE user.active=1 AND tasks_from_yesterday.StartTime = NULL"
```